# Termios disable parity checking on input

Tags: serial-port, beagleboneblack, uart, tty, termios

Is it possible to enable parity generation on output, but not processes the incoming parity? I thought I could manage this by setting PARENB, and then simply NOT setting INPCK.

However as it is, when a character comes in that has parity errors (I see the valid data on analyzer) it is being replaced with *null*(0x00) by the time it is read from ttyO1. Even if I set PARMRK, it will mark with 0xFF, but will still replace with 0x00. I feel like I'm overlooking a flag that tells it not to do this.

I'm running Debian 8.4, 3.8.13-bone79, on the BeagleBoneBlack connected to my logic analyzer.

Comment: *"I'm overlooking a flag that tells it not to do this."* -- Disable **INPCK** and enable **IGNPAR**.  It's **IGNPAR** that controls the substitution.  Beware that framing errors will also go unreported.

Comment: Tried, bailed on it altogether, moved to pru based soft uart that i have full control over.